# How to properly set path params in url using golang http client?

Tags: http, post, go

I'm using net/http package and i would like to set dynamic values to an POST url:

http://myhost.com/v1/sellers/{id}/whatever

How can i set id values in this path parameter?

Comment: Build the URL with fmt.Sprintf

Comment: Cool... there's some more elegant way to do this? or just using another http client library?

Comment: are you looking for url api ? https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#example_ParseQuery

Comment: More elegant how? You're injecting a string into another string, Sprintf does precisely that. What specifically are you looking for beyond "put string x at this position in string y"?

Comment: Probably https://pkg.go.dev/path#Join

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are trying to add params to a URL before you make a server request you can do something like this.

```
const (
    sellersURL = "http://myhost.com/v1/sellers"
)

q := url.Values{}
q.Add("id", "1")

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", sellersURL, strings.NewReader(q.Encode()))
if err != nil {
    return err
}

req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.Close = true

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Comment: This adds query params and not path params

Answer (score 1):

You can use [path.Join](https://pkg.go.dev/path#Join) to build the url. You may also need to [pathEscape](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#PathEscape) the path-params received externally so that they can be safely placed within the path.

```
url1 := path.Join("http://myhost.com/v1/sellers", url.PathEscape(id), "whatever")
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url1, body)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```